# Single board computer draws 0.22 amps: How to calculate how long a 2400 mAH 3s Lipo will provide power?

Tags: current-measurement, amperage, power-measurement

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 single board computer that I'd like use for remote data collection using lithium polymer (Lipo) batteries as the power source. When recording data, my multimeter shows that I am pulling about 0.220 amps. Battery is a 3s 2400 mAH Lipo. What is the calculation for determining how long this battery will power my set-up? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2400 mAh / 220 mA = 10.9 Hours. Not including regulator inefficiency, changes in the battery over time, or peak draws that your multimeter cannot see.

But we have to adjust for the voltage differences.

11.1V * 2.4 Ah = 26.64 Wh available. Take 80% for typical worst case step down regulation, 26.64 Wh * 80% = 21.31 Wh. At 5V, that's 21.32 Wh / 5V = 4.26 Ah.

So 4260 mAh / 220 mA = 19.36 Hours. Again, round down a bit.

So probably more like 18 hours, give or take.

The reality will change depending on how much power is actually taken, or how often the RPI is asleep.

Comment: That matched my experimental evidence perfectly, and was what I thought the calculation might be. The 3s battery outputs 11.1v and is stepped down to 5v for use by the SBC...seems like this would have to be taken into account somehow as well? Thanks.

Comment: @portsample updated to take that into account.